# how to create an sqldump file for backup in netbeans(java)

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I have an issue in creating an sqldump file. Here is the code snip

```
import java.io.*;

public class MySQLBackup {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // MySQL dump command with output file path
            String[] command = {"C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump.exe", "-u", "root", "-p", "mta_db", "-r", "D:/backu1p.sql"};

            // Create ProcessBuilder instance
            
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);

            // Redirect error stream to output stream
            processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);

            // Start the process
            Process process = processBuilder.start();

            // Read the output of the process
            InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line;
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            // Wait for the process to complete
            int exitValue = process.waitFor();

            // Print the output
            System.out.println(output);

            // Check if the process exited successfully
            if (exitValue == 0) {
                System.out.println("Backup completed successfully.");
            } else {
                // Print error stream if process failed
                System.out.println("Backup failed. Exit value: " + exitValue);
                InputStream errorStream = process.getErrorStream();
                InputStreamReader errorStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(errorStream);
                BufferedReader errorBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(errorStreamReader);
                while ((line = errorBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the cooresponding cmd code in cmd, it runs perfectly, but when I run it in netbeans ide, it stop at the processbuilder line. When I futher investigate, I found that the file is created but empty( zero octs) an if I try to delete it, it show an error message stating that mysqldump is using the file. I don't know what to do.

I try changing the process by using process.runtime
`String backupFilePath = PRECLOUD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + "backup.sql";`

```
   String dumpFilePath = "D:/your_dump_file.sql";
           String command = "mysqldump -u root -p  mta_db >"+backupFilePath;
        try {
            
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);.....
```

but still it not working

Comment: You're failing to process stderr. You need to redirect it

Comment: Try with `inheritIO()`. What output do you get? By the way redirection of output with`>` is a shell function, it won't work without a shell.

Comment: If you want to supply the password programmatically, it's `-pThePassword`

Comment: @g00se Thanks I redirect it but the pb is the use no error. The code execute till the line where it to execute the process and then halt. Even to delete the empty file it created I need to kill the process in cmd

Comment: @g00se , and for the password it just empty. It for testing purposes

Comment: You can execute the exact same command in cmd.exe? (And btw I'm assuming you've abandoned the error of trying to do a shell redirect [which isn't necessary anyway owing to `-r`]) btw, you can simplify the command for testing to `new ProcessBuilder(command).inheritIO().start();`